# debug json javascript - Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, debugging

so I can not understand for the life of me why I keep getting 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null starting from line 29 where it says "var stats4". I am trying to apply it to an ID but only stats1,2,3 work. I tried copying and pasting the first part and changing things around. I dont get it.

my entire code is here --  jsfiddle.net/kx4s5egk

```
var request;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
  request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
request.open('GET', 'stats.json');
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if ((request.readyState===4) && (request.status===200)) {

  var items = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

  var stats1 = items[0][0];
  document.getElementById("stats1").innerHTML =
    "<p>" + stats1.countTxt + "</p><p>" + stats1.participantsTxt + "</p><p class='count-blue1'>" + stats1.participantCount + "</p>";

  var stats2 = items[0][1];
  document.getElementById("stats2").innerHTML =
    "<p>" + stats2.countTxt + "</p><p>" + stats2.participantsTxt + "</p><p class='count-blue2'>" + stats2.participantCount + "</p>";


  var stats3 = items[0][2];
  document.getElementById("stats3").innerHTML =
    "<p>" + stats3.countTxt + "</p><p>" + stats3.participantsTxt + "</p><p class='count-blue3'>" + stats3.participantCount + "</p>";


  var stats4 = items[1][0];
  document.getElementById("stats4").innerHTML =
    "<p>" + stats4.countTxt + "</p><p>" + stats4.participantsTxt + "</p><p class='count-blue1'>" + stats4.participantCount + "</p>";

  var stats5 = items[1][1];
  document.getElementById("stats5").innerHTML =
    "<p>" + stats5.countTxt + "</p><p>" + stats5.participantsTxt + "</p><p class='count-blue2'>" + stats5.participantCount + "</p>";


  var stats6 = items[1][2];
  document.getElementById("stats3").innerHTML =
    "<p>" + stats6.countTxt + "</p><p>" + stats6.participantsTxt + "</p><p class='count-blue3'>" + stats6.participantCount + "</p>";



  }
}
request.send();
```

Comment: Does your document have any element with id "stats4"?

Comment: I guess you need to check stats4 element exists in document

Comment: Yes, but when I apply stats 4-5 to id, all the information disappears. probably because im using sass/compass. but right now it works fine for stats1-3

Comment: the weirdest thing is when i put id stats4, it jumps to Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null of line 15 of stats1. I DONT UNDERSTAND

Comment: Would you be able to create a jsFiddle example of the puzzle?

Comment: Question is tagged jQuery. Is there a reason why the code doesn't use jQuery?

Comment: THIS IS EVERYTHING. I didnt know how to input the json file so i just made it into a comment -  http://jsfiddle.net/kx4s5egk/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I notice in your javascript code which are a bit unorthodox and are probably messing things up.

You have everything inside a **window.onload()** function, that's ok. 
But inside the onload function you have two separate calls to the jquery function **$(document).ready** (which is equivalent, but probably more reliable, than window.onload).

One of your calls is the bit that starts with 
    **$(document).ready** 
and the other begins with 
    **jQuery(document).ready**

Try reduce everything (including the window.onload() function) into a single **$(document).ready** function.
You can pull some stuff out into separate functions, but call them from inside $(document).ready

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error message is that you are trying to address a DOM element that doesn't exist. You have coded HTML enough for three items and try to address six.

Something like this is more easily (though probably less efficiently) coded with jQuery.

Sticking with hard-coded HTML, you could do something like this :

```
$.getJSON('stats.json').then(function(data) {
    var i, j, n, stats;
    for(i=0, n=1; i<data.length; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<data[i].length; j++, n++) {
            stats = data[i][j];
            $("#stats" + n).html("<p>" + stats.countTxt + "</p><p>" + stats.participantsTxt + "</p><p class='count-blue'" + (j+1) + ">" + stats.participantCount + "</p>");
        }
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/09yu8zcv/)**

However, you could do better by creating more of the HTML (DOM nodes) dynamically :

```
//First, a tempate for your item entries
var tpl = '<div class="grid1-3">' +
    '<div class="%icon"></div>' +
    '<div class="number_style %count-blue"></div>' +
    '<div class="stats">%stats</div>' +
    '</div>';

$.getJSON('stats.json').then(function(data) {
    var i, j, jj, stats, _tpl;
    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        for(j=0, jj=1; j<data[i].length; j++, jj++) {
            stats = data[i][j];
            _tpl = tpl
                .replace('%icon', 'icon' + jj)
                .replace('%count-blue', 'count-blue' + jj)
                .replace('%stats', "<p>" + stats.countTxt + "</p><p>" + stats.participantsTxt + "</p><p class='count-blue'" + jj + ">" + stats.participantCount + "</p>");
            $("#items").append(_tpl);
        }
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/09yu8zcv/2/)**

I'm sure I haven't addressed every aspect so there's undoubtedly still some work to do.